# Write down values of $a$ and $b$ for which this system of equations has a non unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

As a part of a task I got the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ by solving a system of three equations. The values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ are as follows:

$x=\frac {5-2a-3b}{2b}$

$y=\frac {4a+11b-10}{2b}$

$z=\frac {2a-5}{2b}$

Now I have to find the values of a and b such that the system of equations has a non unique solution.

I have no idea how to proceed here. I understand that by having a non unique solution, the three planes must intersect in a line. Any hints?

The answer at the back of the book is: $a=\frac52$ and $b=0$

**Full question:**

Consider the following system of equations:

$3x+y+z=1$

$x+y-z=4$

$2x+y+bz=a$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Solve the system in terms of $a$ and $b$

Hence, write down the values of $a$ and $b$ for which this system of equations has a non unique solution and state its geometric meaning.

Comment: Write the system as a matrix equation and find when the determinant is zero.

Comment: We have not learnt matrices. Is there any other way?

Comment: Oops, I missed the denominators.

Comment: I think you are missing something. You have $x,y,z$ as functions of $a,b$. What are you solving for?

Comment: Also if $b=0$ as your book says then you can't divide by $b$, so something went wrong somewhere.

Comment: The x, y and z are written correctly (checked at the back of the book, they are exactly the same). I have posted the full question. See the update

Comment: Simplify the setup. Use the first two equations find $x,y$ in terms of $z$. Then the look at solutions to the last equation which is in terms of $z,a,b$ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is incorrect on a subtle but important logical point.

The equation $x = \frac 00$ does not necessarily have an infinite number of solutions.  $\frac 00$ is undefined, so to say that (for example) $x = 5$ is a solution to $x=\frac 00$ is ***wrong***.

On the other hand, $0\cdot x = 0$ does have an infinite number of solutions.  Any number makes that statement true.

It would have been better to ask about

$$2b \cdot x= 5-2a-3b$$

$$2b \cdot y=4a+11b-10$$

$$2b \cdot z=2a-5$$

Here you can see that to convert them all to a form $0 \cdot x = 0$, you must choose $b = 0$:

$$0 \cdot x= 5-2a$$

$$0 \cdot y=4a-10$$

$$0 \cdot z=2a-5$$

And there you can see that choosing $a = \frac 52$ makes all the equations into

$$0 \cdot x= 0$$

$$0 \cdot y= 0$$

$$0 \cdot z= 0$$

Which does have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was not able to understand the fact that in order to have a non unique solution, x, y and z must cancel out and that can only happen if b=0. But now I understand this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution to the problem is partially correct. The $x$, $y$ and $z$ that you solved for are indeed a solution to the system, **if** $b\not= 0$. So with you technique of solving the system you 'lost' the scenario when $b=0$.

So given you did not yet learn anything about matrices and maybe about linear independence and that kind of stuff, a solution technique might be the following:

1. You start solving the system in the way you apparently did: by substitution
2. At some point you have to divide by $b$. From that point on you have to do a case distinction
3. First you finish solving the system as if $b\not= 0$
4. When done, go back to situation before you divided by $b$, and now fill in $b=0$ for all $b$'s, and solve the resulting system.

You'll notice that in step $4$ eventually $x$,$y$ and $z$ all cancel out in the last equation, and you are left with $a=\frac{5}{2}$. And at that point you'll have you non-unique solution, which looks something like

$$x=x$$
$$y=f(x)$$
$$z=g(x,y)$$

(Step 3 can be skipped if you aren't interested in the case $b\not=0$, and of course the order of steps $3$ and $4$ can be changed)

---

Edit: oke here are the details (note there are other ways of doing this, this is just one)

Start by saying (from the second equality)

$$y=4+z-x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

So that by substitution in the first equality

$$x=-z-\frac{3}{2}\ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

And by substitution in the third equality

$$x+4+(b+1)z=a\ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

So now filling in $(2)$ in $(3)$ we find

$$-z-\frac{3}{2}+4(b+1)z=\frac{5}{2}+bz=a$$

So
$$z=\frac{a-\frac{5}{2}}{b}$$

And here we say **wait**. We just divided by $b$, is the allowed? Well it is if $b\not=0$. If we now proceed from here as if indeed $b\not=0$, then we find the solution that you listed in your post.

Now let's see what happens when we say instead that $b=0$. Then we are back in the situation

$$\frac{5}{2}+bz=a$$

And since now $b=0$, this reduces to

$$a=\frac{5}{2}$$

This is what I meant we I said at we obtain a relation from with $x,y$ and $z$ are canceled out.

So we find

$$z=z$$

$$x=-z-\frac{3}{2}$$

$$y=4+z-x$$

As a whole family of solution that are all valid under the assumption that $b=0$ and $a=\frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: I don't understand how to do step 3. Can you explain that in more details. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have already done step $3$. The expressions for $x$, $y$ and $z$ at the top of you post are the result of step $3$. You solved the system as if $b\not=0$

Comment: Ok. What do I do after this step?

Comment: Well, after step $3$ comes step $4$?:p

Comment: I don't understand step 4. How do x, y and z cancel out? Can you show in details.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you solve the first two equations for $x,y$ you get
$x = -{3 \over 2} -z$, $y={11 \over 2} +2 z$.

Then the last equation becomes
$bz + {5 \over 2} = a$.

So, if $b=0$ and $a \neq {5 \over 2}$ there is no solution. Otherwise there is a solution which is $z = {a-{5 \over2} \over b}$ (and the values of $x,y$ follow
from the above formulae).

Comment: You might want to mention what happens when $b=0$ and $a=\frac{5}{2}$ as that's what the question is specifically asking for.

Comment: Ok thanks. I undertand your method.